# int.Parse() with leading zeros

Tags: c#, .net

How do I prevent the code below from throwing a `FormatException`. I'd like to be able to parse strings with a leading zero into ints. Is there a clean way to do this?

```
string value = "01";
int i = int.Parse(value);
```

Comment: Your example code runs fine for me (if I change parse to Parse).

Comment: maybe use `int.Parse(value, Culture.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: Often a leading zero means the number is in Octal (base 8). Is the string `"020"` meant to be `20` (base 10) or `16` (base 10)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your code runs for me, without a `FormatException` (once you capitalize the method properly):

```
string value = "01";
int i = int.Parse(value);
```

But this does ring an old bell; a problem I had years ago, which Microsoft accepted as a bug against localization components of Windows (not .NET).  To test whether you're seeing this, run this code and let us know whether you get a FormatException:

```
string value = "0"; // just a zero
int i = int.Parse(value);
```

**EDIT**: here's my post from Usenet, from back in 2007.  See if the symptoms match yours.

> For reference, here's what we found. 
>   The affected machine had bad data for
>   the registry value
>   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel
>   \International\sPositiveSign]. 
>   Normally, this value is an empty
>   REG_SZ (null-terminated string).  In
>   this case, the string was missing its
>   terminator.  This confused the API
>   function GetLocaleInfoW(), causing it
>   to think that '0' (ASCII number zero)
>   was the positive sign for the current
>   locale (it should normally be '+'). 
>   This caused all kinds of havoc.
>
> You can verify this for yourself with
>   regedit.exe: open that reg value by
>   right-clicking on the value and
>   selecting 'Modify Binary Data'. You
>   should see two dots on the right
>   (representing the null terminator). 
>   If you see no dots, you're affected. 
>   Fix it by adding a terminator (four
>   zeros).
>
> You can also check the value of
>   CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.PositiveSign;
>   it should be '+'.
>
> It's a bug in the Windows localization
>   API, not the class libs.  The reg
>   value needs to be checked for a
>   terminator. They're looking at it.

...and [here's a report on Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=253265) about the issue:

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
int i = Int32.Parse(value, NumberStyles.Any);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
int i = int.parse(value.TrimStart('0'));
```

Comment: I like this approach to sidestep local/base issues. But I think I'll edit the answer because of the value-is-just-0 characters case!

Comment: int i = int.Parse(value.TrimStart('0')); // capital P. editing the answer needs at least 6 characters changed

Comment: what if value is `"0"`?

Answer (score 4):

[TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) will allow you to confirm the result of the parse without throwing an exception. To quote MSDN

> Converts the string representation of
>   a number to its 32-bit signed integer
>   equivalent. A return value indicates
>   whether the operation succeeded.

To use their example

```
   private static void TryToParse(string value)
   {
      int number;
      bool result = Int32.TryParse(value, out number);
      if (result)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number);         
      }
      else
      {
         if (value == null) value = ""; 
         Console.WriteLine("Attempted conversion of '{0}' failed.", value);
      }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try

<strike>int i = Convert.ToInt32(value);</strike>

**Edit**: Hmm. As pointed out, it's just wrapping Int32.Parse. Not sure why you're getting the FormatException, regardless.

Comment: What does Convert.ToInt32 do differently than int.parse?

Comment: Convert.ToInt16 and Convert.ToInt64, is actually a static wrapper method for the int.Parse method. It can be slower than int.Parse if the surrounding code is equivalent.

Comment: @Taylor: You can check with .Net Reflector

Comment: It doesn't, it uses int.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture), in the exact same way.

Comment: @Robert according to reflector they both are exactly the same.

Comment: The only thing that Convert.ToInt32 does different is that it returns zero if the string reference is null. Obviously that makes no difference here.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do anything at all. Adding leading zeroes does not cause a FormatException.

To be 100% sure I tried your code, and after correcting `parse` to `Parse` it runs just fine and doesn't throw any exception.

Obviously you are not showing actual code that you are using, so it's impossible to say where the problem is, but it's definitely not a problem for the `Parse` method to handle leading zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

I have the following codes that may be helpful:

```
int i = int.Parse(value.Trim().Length > 1 ?
    value.TrimStart(new char[] {'0'}) : value.Trim());
```

This will trim off all extra leading 0s and avoid the case of only one 0.

Answer (score 1):

For a decimal number:

```
Convert.ToInt32("01", 10);
// 1
```

For a 16 bit numbers, where leading zeros are common:

```
Convert.ToInt32("00000000ff", 16);
// 255
```

Comment: This did the trick for me. It was treating my values as Octal. It fell over when I tried to parse "018"; but specifying the base as 10 was the way to go. Thanks.