# Int.Parse in C# throwing a Format Exception

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# int.parse issue with leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677516/c-sharp-int-parse-issue-with-leading-zeros)

How can i correct this as a int with leading Zeroes.Actually need to ignore/remove FormatException.

```
string value = "055";
int x = int.Parse(value);
```

Comment: example is complete know ? what should you do ?

Comment: @Learner, what is your current Culture, What are you getting in  `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this..

```
int x = int.parse(value.TrimStart('0'));
```

Answer (score 4):

It works fine on my system.

[image]

Probably the problem is with the current culture, you may try

```
string value = "055";
int x = int.Parse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string value = "055";
int x;

if (int.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,out x ))
{
    //use x
}
//use x ; x will be zero if it fails parsing.
```

Comment: See carefully, I have out set.

Comment: Oh :) Nikhil, Great , you've modified the post. Nice :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Int32.TryParse`

```
string value = "055";
int x = 0;

if(int.TryParse(value, out x))
{
    //use x
}
```

I have tested and x gets 55 and it goes inside if statement.

Comment: Look at Habib answer this might work for you but not for OP.

Comment: @Reniuz: I have tested it. Look at my edit. It is working for OP also.

Comment: How do you know that it works for OP? You tested with same culture as OP?

Comment: May be you can modify your code comment. The comment is written as // rather than \\
That might be a reason that someone  downvoted your answer even after getting an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

you should try to use `TryParse` if you are not sure if it could be parsed

else try

```
int.Parse(value,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If leading zeros is actually a problem (check if you can do `int.Parse("0")` ) then it might be a different issue which is [explained here : localization components of Windows (not .NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1677541/570150)

Answer (score 0):

Leading zeros is C variant actually means that a number should be interpreted as octal, I'm suprised .net throws an exception>

In any event

```
value.TrimStart('0');
```